# Working with engines in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, connection

I am curious about the proper way to close a connection when reading a query through pandas with read_sql_query. I've been using:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine('credentials')
data = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, engine)
```

though it seems like the traditional usage is this:

```
engine = create_engine('credentials')
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute(users_table.select())
for row in result:
    # ....
connection.close()
```

If I am not creating "connection" with engine.connect() as in the second approach, how do I close my connection? Or, is it closed after pd.read_sql_query is finished?

Answer (score 0):

From  http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html

> The Engine is intended to normally be a permanent fixture established up-front and maintained throughout the lifespan of an application. It is not intended to be created and disposed on a per-connection basis; it is instead a registry that maintains both a pool of connections as well as configurational information about the database and DBAPI in use, as well as some degree of internal caching of per-database resources.

The Engine object lazily allocates Connections on demand from an internal pool. These connections aren't necessarily closed when you call the `close` method of the individual Connection objects, just returned to that pool, or "checked in".

If you explicitly need the connections to be closed, you should check in all connections and then call `engine.dispose()`, or you may need to change the Pooling strategy your Engine object uses, see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#pool-switching.